# How to save Stack Overflow answers on Pocket (or any other app)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, ios-app

I spend a lot of time commuting and don't have a 3G connection. That's why I love applications like [Dash](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12) and [Pocket](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pocket/id568494494?ls=1&mt=12) that saves stuff for on the run.

However whenever I save an Stack Overflow page on pocket, it only shows the question, not the answer. Also the Stack Overflow application on Android doesn't save stuff.

Any suggestion on how I can save entire Stack Overflow pages with questions and answers to view later without an Internet connection?

Comment: Are you using a desktop browser, mobile browser, or the Stack Exchange app when you'd like to trigger this "save for later"?

Comment: For the android app, at the bottom of the question click where it says "asked 1 hour ago", etc. and it'll bring up a menu with one option being to share it to another app.

Comment: @3524344 any app on desktop or mobile.. i ride the bus with both

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl if you set your question as an answer i'll award it!

Comment: It would be great if we can save on se app

Comment: Why not just *favorite* the link for future reference?

Answer (score 4):

So every answer on StackOverflow should contain the 'share' link towards the end. I guess you can right click on the answer and select 'Save to Pocket' if you have the Pocket extension for Chrome.

This should work for most platforms as long as you have access to the permalink of the specific answer/question

For ex: On Android, you could copy the link and open it in a new tab and then use the share feature to save it to pocket, assuming you have the Pocket app installed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem for me to save the whole question to Pocket. My strategy is pretty simple:

Open page in Stack Overflow application and click on <kbd>Share</kbd> button and just <kbd>Save to Pocket</kbd>. I know that is it pretty obvious. But there is no need to copy link wherever.

Some screenshots:

### [image: share button]

### [image: share via pocket]

[image: pocket cache]

But seems that Stack Overflow content saved to Pocket is quiet ugly. This is somehow related to *Open Best View* and *Justified Text* options.

Answer (score -1):

One answer should be: Report the issue with a non-working website to Pocket - they are quite often quick with a fix. I have reported this page as an example, as the article view in pocket won't show all answers etc. We will see if they can solve this nicely.