# Is there any read offline option on the Stack Overflow Android app?

Tags: support, feature-request, android-app

I'm trying to save an important Stack Overflow question (like this one: *[Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)*) to read on the go or before bedtime, while I don't have/don't want to use my 3G connection.

Is there an option on the Stack Overflow Android app by which I can do that?

I didn't find any option to do so.

Comment: The short answer is no

Comment: Would be nice to save, say, the starred/ favorites question. But I think it is not a trivial feature to implement. It would need a nice UX/UI to overcome the "question and answers out-of-sync" problem. In some aspects, it may even go against the basic principles of the site.

Comment: There are a plethora of addons and browser features that support this if you can bear to use SO in a browser. Firefox even has a built-in one called Pocket. See this related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256764/2756409

Comment: When 50% of the answers include *multiple* external links for context, what's the point?